# Piping Concurrency and Files

Tags: c, bash, shell, piping

I have a C program which takes a file as an argument, cleans up the file and writes the cleansed data to a new temp file. It then accepts some stdin, cleans it up and sends it stdout.

I have a second file which performs operations on this temp file and on the stdin again.

```
./file_cleanse <file1.txt> | ./file_operation <temp.txt>
```

I either get no or nonsensical stdout from the ./file_operation and I believe this is because it is reading from a file that's still being written/doesn't exist at this point.

Is there any way to make ./file_operation wait until ./file_cleanse has returned a value in bash?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Is `file_operation` reading what `file_cleanse` wrote on its standard output (a pipe), or is it reading more data from the standard input that goes into `file_cleanse`?  Your description is at least ambiguous about that.  How does `file_cleanse` determine the temporary file name?  Why isn't it told which file to write to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
./file_cleanse <file1.txt> > /tmp/temporaryFile
./file_operation <temp.txt> < /tmp/temporaryFile
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, `file_operation` needs to read the standard output of `file_cleanse` after processing the temporary file, but it should not process the temporary file until `file_cleanse` has written some data to its standard output (the standard input of `file_operation`).

If that's correct, then a simple synchronization is for `file_operation` to read (a byte or any convenient larger amount of data) from its standard input.  When this is successful, the `file_cleanse` must have finished with the temporary file; `file_operation` can therefore process the temporary file, and then read the rest of its standard input and process that appropriately.